# Can i push a css grid item to the last position of the css grid with dynamic item length?

Tags: css, position, css-grid

I try to push a item in a css grid to the last position or better to the last line but i dont know if it is possible if i have a random number of elements.

i tried some grid row start and grid row end attributes and some shorthands to push it to the last row

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #f76707;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper > div {
    border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #ffd8a8;
    padding: 1em;
    color: #d9480f;
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.wrapper .item-for-last-line {
  color: #0a8e0a;
  border-color: #0a8e0a;
  background-color: #9df29d;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div class="item-for-last-line">Item for last Line</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/p4nk47w0rk/pen/ZgEeXr

when i set grid-row-start to -2 i thought i can push it to the last row but it did not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use order To set in last position: https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zgYXWa

```
div{order:1}
div.item-for-last-line {order:2}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order
>
> The `order` CSS property sets the order to lay out an item in a `flex` or `grid` container. Items in a container are sorted by ascending `order` value and then by their source code order.

To span 2 columns, it is quiet simple, the rule value is  : `span 2` for `grid-column` .

you might also use :

```
div.item-for-last-line grid-column: span 2 ;}
```

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row
>
> The `grid-row` CSS property is a shorthand property for `grid-row-start` and `grid-row-end` specifying a grid item’s size and location within the grid row by contributing a line, a span, or nothing (automatic) to its grid placement, thereby specifying the inline-start and inline-end edge of its grid area.

**snippet demo**.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div {
  order: 1
}

.wrapper .item-for-last-line {
  color: #0a8e0a;
  border-color: #0a8e0a;
  background-color: #9df29d;
  order: 2;
  grid-column: span 2;
  /* if  needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>One</div>
  <div class="item-for-last-line">Item for last Line</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

If you want it to be layed over your 2 columns.